# Asterisk stasis subscribe

Tags: c, asterisk

I added a custom module to `apps/` folder for registerd to the `ast_channel_topic_all` topic.Unfortunately asterisk occured segment fault every load the moudle.

```
#include "asterisk.h"
#include "asterisk/module.h"
#include "asterisk/json.h"
#include "asterisk/stasis.h"
#include "asterisk/stasis_channels.h"
#include "asterisk/manager.h"

ASTERISK_FILE_VERSION(__FILE__, "$Revision$")
#define AST_MODULE "stasis_test"

static struct stasis_subscription *queue_stasis_message_sub;

static void queue_subscribe_callback(void *data, struct stasis_subscription    *sub, struct stasis_topic *topic, struct stasis_message *message){

    struct ast_channel_blob *payload = stasis_message_data(message);
    // ...
}

static int unload_module(void) {

    stasis_unsubscribe_and_join(queue_stasis_message_sub);

    return 0;
}

static int load_module(void) {

    queue_stasis_message_sub = stasis_subscribe(ast_channel_topic_all(),     queue_subscribe_callback, NULL);

    if ( !queue_stasis_message_sub ) {
        unload_module();
        return AST_MODULE_LOAD_DECLINE;
    }

    return AST_MODULE_LOAD_SUCCESS;
}

AST_MODULE_INFO(
    ASTERISK_GPL_KEY, AST_MODFLAG_LOAD_ORDER, AST_MODULE,
    .load = load_module,
    .unload = unload_module
);
```

What cause this error? Looking forward to your reply.
BTW,The asterisk version I'm using is 13.10.

Comment: Smells like you can't pass `NULL` as third parameter of `stasis_subscribe` function

Comment: This is how asterisk officially did in the source code,should be right.

Answer (score 0):

This question is debug one.

1. Compile asterisk with debug symbols
2. Enable core dump in asterisk.conf
3. Start asterisk.
4. Check core dump with GDB

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+a+Backtrace